# How to automate a Packaged Chrome App using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-app

Can WebDriver automate a Packaged Chrome App?

WebDriver can open the Apps page, click on the packaged app icon, and launch the app which opens in its own app window. But, WebDriver cannot see the app window (`driver.getWindowHandles()` only returns one handle for the original Chrome window), or see any of the web elements inside of the app. And if not WebDriver, are there any other test automation tools that support the latest version of Packaged Chrome Apps?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("ChromePackagedApp.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("chrome://apps/");
WebElement app = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='ChromePackagedApp']/img")); app.click();

Iterator<String> it = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator(); // Print out the handles, only one found (code not shown)
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/iframe")); // Exception thrown because the iframe cannot be found
```

Comment: WebDriver works on HTML pages, so I doubt you'll have any success using it for a Chrome app.  If you're using Windows, you could always try writing an AutoIt test script for automating it.

Comment: This is some simple Java code that demonstrates what I've tried so far.  The content of the app is written in HTML, but is presented in the packaged app 'chrome'.  I'll look at AutoIt, but this automation needs to work on Windows, Linux, and OS X.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.addExtensions(new File("ChromePackagedApp.crx"));  
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  
driver.get("chrome://apps/");  
WebElement app = driver.findElement(By  
    .xpath("//div[@title='ChromePackagedApp']/img"));  
app.click();  
Iterator<String> it = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();  
// Print out the handles, only one found (code not shown)  
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/iframe"));  
// Exception thrown because the iframe cannot be found

Comment: Hi Simon - if you've got extra information, then it's best to edit your question to put it there. That way, anybody reading the question can read everything about it in one place.

Comment: Simon, did you have any luck with this?